# Getting weekday string and not number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the Day of the week as a string and not an integer value from a datetime column from the MySQL Table. So instead of getting 0,1,2.. I would like to have these as Sunday, Monday, tuesday and so on. Is there a date function to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps if you'd bother to RTFM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @MarcB: Ommmmmmmmmmmm :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are looking for DAYNAME

```
 SELECT DAYNAME("2008-05-15") from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **<kbd>[DAYNAME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)</kbd>**

**Query**

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date_column) AS `DayName`
FROM your_table_name;
```